# how to get .gif file in android library development

Tags: android, sdk, gif

I have an app, loading a local .gif animation very well. Then i tried to develop the same code in android library. But then, I am not able to get the .gif file since I didn't there is an assets folder ie I can find C:..\app\build\intermediates\assets    but there is no folder assets in C:..\sdk\build\intermediates  and if i make a folder myself, the build folder is regenerated when i compile the code. But if i put that .gif in drawable, i can't compile it, since only .xml can be inside drawable. Any suggestion is welcomed. Thanks.

```
private void startAnimation() {

    Animation blinkAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.blink);
    tv_paid_amount.startAnimation(blinkAnim);

//        GifDrawable gifFromResource = new GifDrawable(getResources(), //R.drawable.animation6);    //-->this i tried load the file in drawable.

    try {
        GifDrawable gif1 = new GifDrawable(getActivity().getAssets(), "Animation6.gif");
        gif1.setLoopCount(0);
        iv_gif.setImageDrawable(gif1);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I have missed out to add a folder and put the .gif files when building my sdk. Add the gif file into this folder--> C:..\sdk\src\main\assets